# Json to Spring Expression mapping exception

Tags: java, json, spring

When I try to make a POST request (from postman) which has request body as below, I am facing mapping exception :

> Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodResolver]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.freddiemac.security.policy.Policy["accessPolicies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.freddiemac.security.policy.AccessPolicy["condition"]->org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression["evaluationContext"]->org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext["methodResolvers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

POST call - Request Body :

```
{
"accessPolicies": [{
    "policyId": 1,
    "resource": [
        "/my-resource"
    ],
    "action": [
        "POST"
    ],
    "condition": "#claims['userRoles'].contains('developer')", // this is mapped as Spring expression in java
    "effect": "Allow"
}]
```

}

POJO class :

```
private String policyId;
private List<String> resource;
private List<String> action; 
private List<String> role;
private Expression  condition; // import from :  org.springframework.expression.Expression;
```

Could you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a wrapper class for `serviceId` and `version` and `accessPolicies` as list of your current POJO to match the json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expression` interface doesn't have serializer, so receive `String` instead, which does have valid serializer.

Then you can use `SpelExpressionParser` to [parse `String` into a valid `Expression`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-evaluation).

```java
class PostRequestDto {

    private String serviceId;
    private String version;
    private List<AccessPolicy> accessPolicies;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

class AccessPolicy {
    private String policyId;
    private List<String> resource;
    private List<String> action;
    private List<String> role;
    private String condition; // utilize String serializer when accepting SpEL Expression
    private String effect;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity

    // parse received String to derive SpEL Expression 
    public Expression getConditionExpression() {
        // proper error handling omitted for brevity
        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        return expressionParser.parseExpression( this.condition );
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajeshYarraguntla You're welcome.  I'm glad it helped.